# thread explicit scheduling POSIX API gives error

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc

I was trying to create few threads in which some of them will follow explicit scheduling setting provided by developer and wrote following piece of code:

```
pthread_t thid1,thid2,thid3,thid4;

int main()
{

   int ret;
   struct sched_param param1;

   pthread_attr_t pthread_attr1,pthread_attr4;

   ret = pthread_attr_init(&pthread_attr4); 
      if(ret>0) { 
              printf("error in the thread attr initialization\n");  
      }

   ret = pthread_create(&thid4,&pthread_attr4,display_status_thread,NULL);

   if(ret>0) { printf("error in thread creation for producer\n"); exit(4); }   


   pthread_attr_init(&pthread_attr1); 

   //setting the policy to realtime, priority based 
   pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&pthread_attr1,SCHED_FIFO);

   //realtime priority of 1 ( 1-99 is the range) 
   param1.sched_priority = 20;
   pthread_attr_setschedparam(&pthread_attr1, &param1);  

   ret = pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&pthread_attr1,PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED); 

   if(ret>0) { perror("pthread_attr_setinheritsched failed."); exit(1); }

   ret = pthread_create(&thid1,&pthread_attr1,func1,NULL);
   //Here comes error " error in creating func1 thread.
   if(ret>0) { printf("error in thread creation for func1\n"); exit(1); }

   ret = pthread_create(&thid2,NULL,func2,NULL);
   if(ret>0) { printf("error in thread creation for func2\n"); exit(2); } 

   ret = pthread_create(&thid3,NULL,func3,NULL);
   if(ret>0) { printf("error in thread creation for func3\n"); exit(3); } 


   pthread_join(thid1,NULL);

   pthread_join(thid2,NULL);

   pthread_join(thid3,NULL);

   pthread_join(thid4,NULL);

   exit(0);

}
```

I am getting the error at the place where I am setting inherited scheduling creating explicit thread.

What is going wrong? Is the usage of `pthread_attr_setinheritsched()` is incorrect in syntax or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you would find the problem if you showed the error your getting

> ERRORS         top
>
> ```
>    EAGAIN Insufficient resources to create another thread.
>
>    EAGAIN A system-imposed limit on the number of threads was
>           encountered.  There are a number of limits that may trigger
>           this error: the RLIMIT_NPROC soft resource limit (set via
>           setrlimit(2)), which limits the number of processes and
>           threads for a real user ID, was reached; the kernel's system-
>           wide limit on the number of processes and threads,
>           /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max, was reached (see proc(5)); or
>           the maximum number of PIDs, /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max, was
>           reached (see proc(5)).
>
>    EINVAL Invalid settings in attr.
>
>    EPERM  No permission to set the scheduling policy and parameters
>           specified in attr. ATTRIBUTES         top
> ```

This might print the correct error message.

```
errno = ret; 
perror(msg); 
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Edit: The problem was `EPERM` and by escalating to `sudo` it now runs.

Comment: The error is following: `: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @AmarjeetSharma so the OS is unhappy with your settings (EPERM), different OS's have different limits and might not offer FIFI, priority or inherit. Try removing each to see which one it is in this case or escalate your rights on the machine, run as admin or sudo depending on your OS.

Comment: Thanks it helped. The real issue was permission by using sudo the program is running well. Thanks again.